# php preg_match() not working, find a var

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

header.php file

```
<?php
 echo 'this is example '.$adv['name'].' , this is another.....';
```

main.php file

```
<?php

if(preg_match('/$adv[(.*?)]/',file_get_contents('header.php'),$itext)){
    echo $itext[1].'';
}
```

show empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more efficient solution:

Pattern ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1eMPWv/1)):

```
/\$adv\[\K[^]]*?(?=\])/
```

PHP Implementation:

```
if(preg_match('/\$adv\[\K[^]]*?(?=\])/','this is example $adv[name]',$itext)){
    echo $itext[0];
}
```

Output for `$itext`:

```
name
```

Notice that by using `\K` to replace the capture group, the targeted string is returned in the "full string" match which effectively reduces the output array by 50%.

You can see the demo link for explanation on individual pieces of the pattern, but basically it matches `$adv[` then resets the matching point, matches all characters between the square brackets, then does a positive lookahead for a closing square bracket which will not be included in the returned match.

Regardless of if you want to match different variable names you could use: `/\$[^[]*?\[\K[^]]*?(?=\])/`. This will accommodate `adv` or any other substring that follows the dollar sign.  By using `Negated Character Classes` like `[^]]` instead of `.` to match unlimited characters, the regex pattern performs more efficiently.

If `adv` is not a determining component of your input strings, I would use `/\$[^[]*?\[\K[^]]*?(?=\])/` because it will be the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

this regular expression will work

```
/\$adv\[(.*?)\]/
```

You need to escape symbols $,[,] using \ before them
since they have special meaning in regular expressions